# Is it possible to have my Android device see hand gestures to turn on the screen and scroll?

Tags: lock-screens, touchscreen

While I am cooking with dirty and wet hands, I want to see the recipe on my smartphone without dirtying it.

How may I turn on the display and scroll without touching the phone?

Is there a setting or application that makes my device react on hand gestures to turn on the screen and scroll?

(I do not know how to categorize this question with the available tags if you know a better tag please feel free to improve the categorization)

Comment: As *Is there an app for X* questions are off topic here (see our [FAQ]), I altered your question minimally; it should still fit your intention. What you describe comes close to "air gestures", which are partly supported by e.g. [Wave Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MarksThinkTank.WaveControl); you might also want to check with [Nanogest](http://www.nanocritical.com/nanogest/). Full support unfortunately seems not to be available to all devices; e.g. the [S4 has it](http://touchlessgeneration.com/discover-touchless/testing-of-air-gestures-on-the-galaxy-s4/).

Comment: @Izzy Comments are for asking questions about the question, not for giving answers

Comment: I didn't consider "hints" as answers. Answers are giving *solutions* -- my above comment just shows *similarities*: *Wave Control* just works for music and video in selected apps, *Nanogest* is an SDK for developers to integrate this functionality into their apps, and "buying a S4" is no answer on how to get this functionality on any device (quote: *on my smartphone without dirtying it*), but rather the opposite (getting a device for this functionality). So: this was just for clarifications on terms, not an answer. But I'm glad you consider it helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend getting [Air Swiper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.helmisek.project.airswiper) with which you can turn on your device just by swiping above the sensor  (which is located with your front camera), and you can also turn it off by swiping as well.